# How accurate is this geolocation calculation?

Tags: ios, geolocation, coffeescript, titanium, trigonometry

I'm playing around with Titanium, and am using this formula to calculate distance

```
    toRad = (x) ->
      x * Math.PI / 180

    toDeg = (x) ->
      x * 180 / Math.PI

    startingLat = hsc.models.startingPosition.latitude
    startingLon = hsc.models.startingPosition.longitude
    currentLat = e.coords.latitude
    currentLon = e.coords.longitude
    R = 6371
    dLat = toRad(currentLat - startingLat)
    dLon = toRad(currentLon - startingLon)
    a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(toRad(startingLat)) * Math.cos(toRad(currentLat)) *
        Math.sin (dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = R * c;

    hsc.models.positionUpdateCallback (d * 1093.6133) if hsc.models.positionUpdateCallback
    console.log "distance is [#{d}]km"
```

I am testing as follows.

Start at point A.
Enable tracking.
End at point B.
Record value. 
Clear.
Enable tracking.
Go back to point A.
Record value

In 6 runs I have got values between 122 and 135.  [This tool](http://www.freemaptools.com/measure-distance.htm) tells me the distance is 124.9 yards.

And that might be the difference between a 8 iron and a 7 iron, so this is important people!!

Edit: I'm wondering if the way I get the initial position is flawed.

Here is how I start tracking when user taps start.

```
hsc.models.startTracking = (onUpdate) ->
  return if hsc.models.isTracking
  Ti.App.idleTimerDisabled = true;

  Ti.Geolocation.setFrequency 100
  Titanium.Geolocation.setAccuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
  Titanium.Geolocation.setDistanceFilter 0

  hsc.models.positionUpdateCallback = onUpdate
  hsc.models.isTracking = true;
  Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener 'location', hsc.models.locationUpdate
```

and here is how I finish up, when user taps End.

```
if hsc.models.isTracking is true
    Ti.App.idleTimerDisabled = false;
    hsc.models.isTracking = false
    hsc.models.startingPosition = null
    Ti.Geolocation.setFrequency 500000
    Titanium.Geolocation.setDistanceFilter 10
    Ti.Geolocation.removeEventListener 'location', hsc.models.locationUpdate
```

in `locationUpdate` I do

```
if not hsc.models.startingPosition
    hsc.models.startingPosition = e.coords
else
    #do the calculation
```

So basically I just start receiving updates, and when I get the first one, I set the initial position.  I wonder if I need to do an initial `getCurrentPosition`, then register the location callback handler.  This might handle the case where the first update is a bit delayed a bit better.

MORE INFO

So I implemented and tried out the new strategy -- getting the starting location, then beginning to listen for changing events (not moving while step 1 occurs) and I still see pretty big discrepancies.  I went from A -> B and got 134 yards, and then from B -> A and got 117 yards.  I ran it going from my door to daycare to get the offspring, and registered 2220 yards, and from my parked car back to my door got 2268 yards.

Whats more, sitting in the same place, it registers a change in position, up 20 yards!

I must be doing something wrong here.....

Answer (score 1):

As a former Engineering Technology instructor, I can tell you that getting an accurate GPS fix takes A LOT more time than a few seconds.  Being within 20 yards is more than accurate enough for turn-by-turn street navigation, because the app snaps to the location of the nearest valid street location.

You are trying to do what's called Real Time Kinematics GPS.  Even the high-end (tens of thousands of dollars) gps units used for land surveying and agricultural equipment guidance  require a stationary Master unit that takes at least 20 minutes to get a stable location that can then be used for error corrections in the wirelessly connected rover units. Those units under these conditions can get you within a fraction of an inch, which you don't really need.

However, I can personally assure you that the amount of time that the device stays still at point A and Point B will be a major factor in the accuracy of your distance.

Comment: how come it 'drifts' so much.  Like I said, sitting in my chair, up to 25 yards?

Comment: Because constant changes in the Ionosphere and Troposphe interfere with the GPS signal.  See this link.  http://goo.gl/iSC8Z

Comment: so you are saying there is no way for a phone to get a reading accurate to a couple yards, reliably.  Now what about using google maps data?  How accurate is picking 2 locations and calculating the distance between them?

Comment: There is an accuracy on iOS that is better than "Best", and it's called "Best for Navigation".  Although, I don't know if that's accessible in Titanium.  The GIS data that Google uses is usually very accurate because it comes from reliable sources like professional land surveys.